# Add additional column with current date during copy data tool in Azure synapse

Tags: datetime, azure-synapse

I need to add an additional column while loading my file through the copy data tool in Azure Synapse Analytics and that column should pick the current_dateTime when I load the data.

I am facing the problem that's when I add the function current_dateTime as a value it takes "current_dateTime" as a string instead of the actual date.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try out the expression @utcnow() and it should work .

[image]

I got this as the output

[image]